# Java boxing and unboxing

Tags: java, integer, boxing, unboxing

I have an example in which I cannot determine the number of boxing(s) and unboxing(s), which taking place in the Java code below :

```
int x = 5;
Integer y = x + x;
```

From my point of view I see one type of boxing (Integer y = x + x). Am I wrong? Is there any unboxing as well?

Comment: You're right. There is no unboxing.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **unboxing**. Just **boxing** happening.

First the expression `x+x` calculated which is an `int` and that is **boxed** to `Integer`.

So in the whole statement there is no conversion of `Integer` to `int`, hence no **unboxing**.

Comment: Exactly how I thought about it! Thank you for your answer

Comment: `Integer to int` you meant `int to Integer` right ?

Comment: @Ravi I am telling, that is not happening.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ did you meant *whole statement there is **no** conversion of Integer to int* ?

Comment: Yes. There is only `int` to `Integer`. Not `Integer` to `int`.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ then you missed ***no*** in your post. :D

Comment: Hello again! I wanted to ask how many boxings and unboxings take place at the code below?

`Integer x = 5;
int y = x + x;`

I would say none, but I am not sure if I am right

Answer (score 1):

As per your question we first define an int value and assign it to x variable (no boxing un-boxing required), Then you are adding 2 integer variable no boxing un-boxing required.
Now you are assigning a int result to Integer means changing from primitive to non primitive data type. 
Java autoboxing can convert int to integer there here autoboxing is there which is boxing.